# My Spring Boot JAR file can't be deployed via Maven/Eclipse, it always shuts down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

When I run the Spring Boot App, it always shuts down, it never gets attached to a tomcat server, even if I already set up the dependency on pom.xml. Is there something wrong with my setting?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExampleSimulator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ExampleSimulator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
           <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The log goes as follows:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2021-09-12 07:13:21.013  INFO 5992 --- [           main] com.example.Application   : Starting Application on User-PC with PID 5992 (D:\Example\target\classes started by User in D:\Example)
2021-09-12 07:13:21.016  INFO 5992 --- [           main] com.example.Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-12 07:13:21.049  INFO 5992 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6f3b5d16: startup date [Sun Sep 12 07:13:21 ICT 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-09-12 07:13:21.725  INFO 5992 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-12 07:13:21.904  INFO 5992 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-12 07:13:21.935  INFO 5992 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-12 07:13:21.942  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2021-09-12 07:13:21.987  INFO 5992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2021-09-12 07:13:21.989  INFO 5992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2021-09-12 07:13:22.014  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2021-09-12 07:13:22.088  INFO 5992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2021-09-12 07:13:22.854  INFO 5992 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-12 07:13:23.395  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2021-09-12 07:13:23.396  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2021-09-12 07:13:23.400  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2021-09-12 07:13:23.425  INFO 5992 --- [           main] com.example.Application   : Started Application in 2.585 seconds (JVM running for 3.086)
2021-09-12 07:13:23.428  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6f3b5d16: startup date [Sun Sep 12 07:13:21 ICT 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-09-12 07:13:23.429  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2021-09-12 07:13:23.429  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2021-09-12 07:13:23.430  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-12 07:13:23.431  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-09-12 07:13:23.433  INFO 5992 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Is there something I need to remove or fix? My Maven occasionally had corrupted files so sometimes I update manually.

Help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First can you explain what you mean by `My Maven occasionally had corrupted files so sometimes I update manually.`?

Comment: Don't exclude dependencies and re-add other version only if you know what you are doing. Also don't use versions of things which are provided by spring boot (hibernate-validator) if you need newer versions use more recent version of spring boot (2.5.4 most recent)...

Comment: Please provide a debug log of your running code (until shutdown) in addition to @khmarbaise's comments.

Comment: @yoni The debug log has been provided into the main topic

Comment: @khmarbaise Occasionally some of the dependency jar files is corrupted. When I tried to force update with Maven, they still didn't fix the corrupted jar that I have to download manually. The effect includes sometimes the dependency either producing error or being ignored altogether as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The shutdown is initiated from `Thread-2`. Judging by its name or rather lack of a proper naming scheme, this thread is probably generated by you (not Spring). Do you execute some code in a separate thread?

Comment: @KristianWijaya Please read https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ sounds like those things happen based on download issues...